# Do not send emails to subscribers in the Reporting Configuration. Kentico 9

Tags: email, kentico

After creating a subscription in the Reporting Configuration, the emails are not sent at the specified time, but if you perform any actions on the site, the emails will be sent. This is the problem of the virtual machine on which the site or IIS is deployed. Or does the feature Kentico.

Prompt in what there can be a problem and how the system of sending of emails inin the Reporting Configuration works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct behavior. Kentico checks for e-mails that are to be sent at the end of requests which means that if there are no requests, no e-mails are sent. If you need some tasks to be send at a specified time, you need to use **Windows scheduler** and configure task (e-mmail sending) to use it. See official [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/scheduling-tasks/installing-the-scheduler-windows-service) for more detail.s

Answer (score 0):

Another option to Enn's, is to use a service like UpTime Robot to continually visit your page (like every 5 minutes), this not only generates a request but also will help keep your site awake and from going to sleep if you can't manually set the Worker Processor to never go to sleep.

Windows Scheduler is the most reliable, but UpTime robot has worked well for us.

https://uptimerobot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Scheduled Tasks" module there is a schedule task called "Report subscription sender". This task runs every minute and is responsible for checking your subscriptions and sending e-mails based on your configuration. This task runs within the Kentico instance. By default IIS will put the site/app pool to sleep after x (default 20) minutes of idle and the scheduled tasks are no longer able to run. When you hit the site it wakes the process back up and the scheduled task is able to run again. You can go into IIS and configure the "Idle Time-out (minutes)" for the application pool see this link https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/iis-no-sleep-idle-and-autostart-with-values for a pretty good illustration. You can also adjust the app pool recycle intervals but that is probably not necessary for your issue.

The other option, as mentioned by Enn, is to install the Kentico Scheduler Windows service which always runs and configure that scheduled task to run in the service.